# How do I use Bash to get a Ruby variable?

Tags: ruby, bash

I have a Ruby script called `script.rb`, which looks like this:

```
puts 16
```

I have a Bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOME_VARIABLE=$(ruby script.rb)
```

I want `SOME_VARIABLE` to be equal to `16`, or whatever else I decide to `puts` from `script.rb`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you even tried what you are asking? It works exactly as you have described in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it as such.

```
#!/bin/bash
SOME_VARIABLE=`ruby script.rb`
```

If for example you want to export an environment variable.

```
export SOME_ENV=`ruby script.rb`
$ echo $SOME_ENV
16
```

More information on [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).